# Using Spring without exposing the dependencies to the Client app

Tags: java, spring, osgi

I'm writing a Java API for several clients, and would internally like to use Spring and it's several features, but I don't want to expose to the client my dependencies.

Is this possible?

So if my client uses a different version of spring would they be insulated from my internal Spring dependencies.

If so, would my spring dependencies be bundled internally inside my jar?  As well as would a custom class loader be required by my client application?

I have heard you can use this through OSGI bundles, but I'm wondering if this would satisfy my requirement.

The clients of my API wouldn't be OSGI enabled or we have no current environment that utilizes OSGI bundles.

Comment: OSGi can certainly help with this, because Spring would become an internal implementation detail of your bundle. You could use something like Spring-DM or Blueprint to expose services from your bundle, and client bundles would bind to those services without knowledge of the implementation details.

Comment: OSGi can help only if you are deploying in an OSGi environment, which you haven't specified.  Can you give more detail as to how your API is used.  I am assuming it is used as a library for other apps, is this correct?

Comment: Depending on what Spring features you would like to use. If you plan to use `JdbcTemplate` or `@Autowired` then you can't avoid dependency on Spring because it would be a compile-time dependency. If you plan to use IoC only, then you can avoid dependency on Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really feasible, or desirable to do so.  Why would you want to "hide" the dependencies?  Would you also want to hide a dependency on whatever logging package you may be using (for example)?

If you have the dependencies in your implementation, then they are best published as it will cause a lot less grief on the part of users of your API since they will know what conflicts may exist before they even attempt to use your code.

Don't forget, your users are actually developers and I am sure that they would rather be aware of any landmines or requirements up front.

**Edit - Regarding OSGi:**

OSGi will definitely take care of your conflicting dependencies issues, but it also would rely on deploying in an OSGi environment, which you haven't mentioned is the case for your clients.  In addition, it is still not recommended to "hide" those dependencies in a bundle.  The very nature of OSGi allows those conficting depencies to cooexist in the same application.

Comment: Hiding the dependencies eliminates the following:  What is this "jar" going to pull in for me that will conflict with my version of "X".  Example 1) A client application uses spring 2.5 while internally I use spring 3.0.  I don't want to force the client to upgrade.  The intent is to internalize my dependencies so that the client doesn't care whats internally referenced.  In my case we have spring clients and NON spring clients, but I don't want to directly tell them now, go load up a context and include 40 new jars for using my API.  Just wondering if this is even easily possible in Java.

Comment: This is not practically doable.  OSGi can help, but this would force your clients to use OSGi, or you will have to embed OSGi inside your implementation (never done this but I believe it is doable - Neil can probably confirm).  Basically you will have to try some sort of classloader manipulation to hide those dependencies.  Then the next problem will be that you will have to redeploy your lib when a bug is found in any of your dependencies, instead of simply having your client get Spring 3.0.1 (for example).  I think this makes your solution more complicated and fragile in the long run.

Comment: Robin - I agree that using OSGi for this purpose is predicated on actually running in an OSGi environment. Furthermore I would not advise OP to convert his environment if it is *only* for the reasons set out in his question. On the other hand if he does build on OSGi and uses it to hide implementation details from consumers of his API then he will end up with a simple, stabler and less fragile solution in the long run.

Comment: @Neil - I agree, but he hasn't said anything to the effect that his clients are using OSGi.  I would suspect not, since I think he would have already gone that route as a solution if they were.  Of course even if OSGi was acceptable, I would still not recommend "hiding" the dependencies, as that would basically require packaging the dependencies within his own bundle, hidden from the world so to speak.  The dependencies should still be exposed, but the classloading issues due to versioning would simply go away.

Comment: @Robin - Yes I agree: he or his clients are probably not using OSGi so he cannot rely on a solution that involves OSGi. For the second part, I sort of agree. The dependencies of his bundle should be explicit so that they can be managed by a deployer, but they should not be exposed via his exported APIs.

Comment: @Neil - Then we completely agree.  I wasn't implying that he export the packages himself, only that he should not embed the dependent jars within his own bundle to 'hide' them. That is, to effectively put a /lib in his bundle instead of importing the dependencies.

Comment: Correct, my environment doesn't currently use OSGI bundles.  I remember extracting some jar I found off the net that had internal jars and a completely customized manifest.mf.  I suppose it was using some OSGI enabled framework like spring to support internalizing it's jars and not breaking clients.

The fact that you can even internalize jars inside a jar was quite interesting, which insulates any changes inside your "module".  I guess.